# Add link to WooComerce my account page using hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, hook-wordpress

I found this code from @LoicTheAztec that adds allows you to add some extra text to the My Account - Dashboard tab in WooComerce.

I am trying to add a hyper link to it however my php knowledge and syntax is appalling and I clearly can't use the standard a href html to do this as this throws an error : *syntax error, the unexpected identifier "https", expecting ")"*

Any help on how I could add a URL to this would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Code :

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_content', 'action_woocommerce_account_content' );
function action_woocommerce_account_content(  ) {
    global $current_user; // The WP_User Object

    echo '<p>' . __("<a href="https://google.com"> Request Wholesale account </a>", "woocommerce") . '</p>';
};
```

Comment: If you want it only to dashboard use woocommerce_account_dashboard hook instead. Use single quote echo '<p>' . __('<a href="https://google.com"> Request Wholesale account </a>', 'woocommerce') . '</p>';

Comment: Thank you Martin, this worked perfectly and thanks for the tip about the dashboard hook!

Answer (score 1):

You are using double quotes twice which cancel each others. simpler way to do it. also you need to separate the translation function from the html.

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_account_content', 'action_woocommerce_account_content' );
    function action_woocommerce_account_content() {
        global $current_user; // The WP_User Object
        ?>
        <p><a href="https://google.com"><?php _e( 'Request Wholesale account', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a></p>
        <?php
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
add_action('woocommerce_account_content', 'action_woocommerce_account_content');

function action_woocommerce_account_content() {
    global $current_user; // The WP_User Object

    echo '<p>' . sprintf(esc_html__('%1$s Request Wholesale account %2$s', 'woocommerce'), '<a href="https://google.com">', '</a>') . '</p>';
}
```

Always [escape/secure output](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/security/securing-output/) for security using like `esc_html__`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this with Martin's help. Thanks for all the other suggestions too.

The way I ended up doing it was to use the Dashboard hook as suggested and the single quote echo.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_dashboard', 'custom_account_dashboard_content' );
function custom_account_dashboard_content(){
    echo '<div>' . __('<br><b><a href="https://google.com"> REQUEST WHOLESALE ACCOUNT </a></b>', 'woocommerce') . '</div>';
}
```